# an Interface -two method with same name and Signature

Tags: c#

I had an interview question-C#, is it possible to implement in a class, inheriting from an interface has two methods with same name and same signature?

Comment: Type it out and let us know how that goes...

Comment: Any question that can be answered simply by reading documentation or spending a few minutes testing for yourself should never be asked here. This site is for the stuff you can't work out for yourself, not stuff you can't be bothered to work out.

Comment: I don't understand the question, why is the interface relevant?

Comment: public interface ITest
    {
        void method(int i, int j);
        void method(int i, int j);

    }
    class TestImp : ITest
    {
        
    }

Answer (score 1):

Not with the same interface. If you had 2 interfaces with methods with the same signature, one class implementation would fulfill both.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, yes a single class would fulfil 2 separate interfaces that have the same method signature.

However, you can also provide a different implementation for each interface. This can be referred to as 'explicit interface implementation'. For instance...

```
    interface ITest1
    {
        void Test();
    }

    interface ITest2
    {
        void Test();
    }

    public class TestImpl : ITest1, ITest2
    {
        void ITest1.Test()
        {
            
        }

        void ITest2.Test()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

When using explicit interface implementation, you cannot call the method from the concrete type, i.e. `new TestImpl().Test()`. You can only call the implementations specific to each interface when you have an interface-specific reference. For example.

```
(new TestImpl() as ITest1).Test();
(new TestImpl() as ITest2).Test();
```

Or...

```
ITest1 test = new TestImpl();
test.Test();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but the implementations must be private"? They are publically accessible.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner Yes you're right! I was referring to the fact that using explicit interface implementation in this manner 'hides' the methods when using the concrete type. You're right, I was not being technically correct. I've amended the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to implement in a class, inheriting from an **interface** has two methods with same name and same signature?

No, with implementing one interface you cannot.

> is it possible to implement in a class, inheriting from **interfaces** has two methods with same name and same signature?

yes, Tom's answer is showing how.

But when two interface requires your class to implement a method which have same name and signature, you can also do like below.

```
interface ILandAnimal
{
    void ToWalk();
    void ToBreed();
}
interface IWaterAnimal
{
    void ToSwim();
    void ToBreed();
}

public class Amphibians : ILandAnimal, IWaterAnimal
{
    //only one implementation of ToBreed ()
    //  (which is there in both interface)
    public void ToBreed() { }
    public void ToWalk() { }
    public void ToSwim() { }
}
```

In most of the cases, it really doesn't matters (and also doesn't make much sense) to have two methods for two interfaces as both interfaces contract with class to implement **one** such method which have same name and same signature as interface contains.

and implementing only one method satisfy this contract of both interfaces.

for example : In above code, Both Land Animal's and Water Animal's interfaces require their inheritors to have a functionality to breed. And class `Amphibians` does inherit both of them as it must have all functionalities of Land and water animal. Still it will have only one way (implementation) to breed. so making two methods for breeding is not required.

**But** this approach of implementation will not work if your class must have one behavior on interface1's method and different behavior on interface2's method. And in such cases you must go with Tom's answer